# Xamarin. Не запускает приложение - ни в железе, ни в эмуляторе

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Доброе время суток! Решил вместо AS попробовать Xamarin в VS2019. Вроде бы все замечательно - ламповый VS с C#. Но вот запустить типичный "Hello World" xamarin.forms ни в железе, ни в эмуляторе не получается. Сам же *.apk в обоих случаях устанавливается без проблем. При попытке открыть, приложение тут же закрывается.
Эмулятор api28, на железе 21 и 24. Как решить сие проблему?

Comment: Как и всегда, смотреть логи ошибок при падении. Так подсказать сложно.

Comment: Запуск и отладка приложений api28 и ниже сопровождается ошибкой: adb 1000 deployment failed. И все.

Comment: Нужно больше информации в вопросе, пока он слишком общий без какой либо конкретики. Нужно добывать логи падения.